# Is there a better and fast way to check user input beside IF statement using python and streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, filter, streamlit

I have a dataframe that includes about 22 columns. I want to allow the user to perform a custom filter based on his input. Where the app displays a list of checkboxes that the filter is made based on the checked one.

Example of dataframe:

```
data = {'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Tom'],
        'nickname':['jack','krish','karim','joe', 'joe'],
        'date':['2013','2018','2022','2013','2013'],
        'loc':['loc1','loc2','loc1','loc3','loc2'],
        'dep':['manager','accounting','sales','sales','HR'],
        'status':['in','out','out','in','in'],
        'desc':['the boss ','employee with good attitude','can work harder',' he got the will to work in a team',''],
        'age':[20, 18, 19, 18, 22]}
```

Each field can be checked to take the user input.

The more I have fields the more I will use IF statement.
Is there a better and fast way to do it?

The code:

```py
import streamlit as st 
import pandas as pd

data = {'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Tom'],
        'nickname':['jack','krish','karim','joe', 'joe'],
        'date':['2013','2018','2022','2013','2013'],
        'loc':['loc1','loc2','loc1','loc3','loc2'],
        'dep':['manager','accounting','sales','sales','HR'],
        'status':['in','out','out','in','in'],
        'desc':['the boss ','employee with good attitude','can work harder',' he got the will to work in a team','']
        'age':[20, 18, 19, 18, 22]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.write(df)
df_result_search = pd.DataFrame() 


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)
date_sort=df.date.unique()

searchcheckbox_name_nickname = st.checkbox("Name or Nickname ",value = False,key=1)
searchcheckbox_age = st.checkbox("age",value = False,key=2)
searchcheckbox_date = st.checkbox("Date",value = False,key=3)
searchcheckbox_loc = st.checkbox("Loc",value = False,key=4)

if searchcheckbox_name_nickname:
    name_search = st.text_input("name")
    nickname_search = st.text_input("nickname")
else:
    name_search = ''
    nickname_search = ''

if searchcheckbox_age:   
    age_search = st.number_input("age",min_value=0)
else:
    age_search = 0

if searchcheckbox_date:
    date_search = st.select_slider("Select date",date_sort,key=1)
   
else:
    date_search = ''

if searchcheckbox_loc:
    loc_search = st.multiselect("Select location",df['loc'].unique())
   
else:
    loc_search = ''


if st.button("search"):
    # 1. only name/nickname is checked
    if searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not searchcheckbox_age and not searchcheckbox_date and not searchcheckbox_loc:
        # if name is specified but not the nickname
        if name_search != '' and nickname_search == '':
            df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)]
        # if nickname is specified but not the name
        elif name_search == '' and nickname_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)]
        # if both name and nickname are specified
        elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False))]
        # if user does not enter anything
        else:
            st.warning('Please enter at least a name or a nickname')
    
    # .  name/nickname + loc is checked
    elif searchcheckbox_name_nickname and searchcheckbox_loc and not searchcheckbox_date and not searchcheckbox_age:
        if name_search != '' and nickname_search == '' and loc_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)& (df['loc'].isin(loc_search))]
        # if nickname is specified but not the name
        elif name_search == '' and nickname_search != '' and loc_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False) & (df['loc'].isin(loc_search))]
        # if both name and nickname are specified
        elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != '' and loc_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['loc'].isin(loc_search))]
       
    # . name/nickname + date is checked
    elif searchcheckbox_name_nickname and searchcheckbox_date and not searchcheckbox_age:
        if name_search != '' and nickname_search == '' and date_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)& (df['date'] == date_search)]
        # if nickname is specified but not the name
        elif name_search == '' and nickname_search != '' and date_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False) & (df['date'] == date_search)]
        # if both name and nickname are specified
        elif name_search != '' and nickname_search != '' and date_search !='':
            df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['date'] == date_search)]
       

    # . only age is checked
    elif not searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not searchcheckbox_date and searchcheckbox_age:
        if age_search != 0:
            df_result_search = df[df['age'] == age_search]
            
    # . only date is checked
    elif not searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not searchcheckbox_age and searchcheckbox_date:
        if date_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[df['date']==date_search]
    
    # . only loc is checked         
    elif not searchcheckbox_name_nickname and not searchcheckbox_age and not searchcheckbox_date and searchcheckbox_loc:
        if loc_search != '':
            df_result_search = df[df['loc'].isin(loc_search)]
    
    # . if all are checked
    else:
        df_result_search = df[(df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False)) & (df['age'] == age_search) & (df['date'] == date_search) & (df['loc'] == loc_search)]
        
                    
    st.write("{} Records ".format(str(df_result_search.shape[0])))
    st.dataframe(df_result_search)
```

based on the answer of **@Jérôme Richard** this the error that is displayed how to fix it and where is the error ?

[image]

Comment: You can factorize some parts of the code. For example the two first main ifs are nearly the same. If all fields are computed the same way, a simple loop can do the job but this appear not to be the case in your code. Regarding the rules you defined having more ifs is normal. The general solution to reduces the number of conditions statements in the code is to treats fields as independent as possible and iterate over fields using a generic code.

Comment: What you mean treats fields as independent as possible 
How can i do this??

In my app the user can filter based on many fields   each time.

Mean the user can filter based on 
&#39;Name with date  with age&#39; 
Ss he can filter based on 
Loc with status  with nickname with age 

Hope that i make the example understandable.
And the user is not limited with this example only.

Comment: Ok, but are the filter(s) set on each field independent of other fields? If no, then there is no simple solution.

Comment: Yes each field is independent of other fields where the user can filter each time on different combined fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the filtering of each field is independent, you can filter the row of the dataframe by producing a column (ie. Numpy array) of boolean for each filter. Then you can apply several logical-ORs and logical-ANDs to mix the result of each filter so to produce a final filtering mask. Here is a simplified example:

```py
import numpy as np

names_filter_mask = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)
nickname_filter_mask = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)

# One condition per column.
# If there is many column you can use a for loop 
# iterating over a predefined list of filtered column
# and store the filter mast in a N x len(df) array.

if should_filter_name():
    name_search = get_name_from_user_interface()
    names_filter_mask = df['name'].str.contains(name_search, case=False, na=False).to_numpy()

if should_filter_nickname():
    nickname_search = get_nickname_from_user_interface()
    nickname_filter_mask = df['nickname'].str.contains(nickname_search, case=False, na=False).to_numpy()

# Mix the filters
merged_filter_mask = names_filter_mask & nickname_filter_mask

# Get the filtered lines
df_result_search = df[merged_filter_mask]
```

Comment: so based on your answer if i want to add filter for **loc** and **date** field first i create `loc mask`  `date mask`
then i create `if statement` for each filter and at the end a `merge all the 4 filters`

did i get it right ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly that.

Comment: i tried your answer  it display the below error :
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,8) (5,8)`

Comment: Well, you should have 1D boolean array and not 2D ones, but it is hard to know why you get 2D arrays without the tested code. All the filter should have a size of `len(df)`.

Comment: so how to know what is the error and how to fix the 2D

Comment: i tried to use .dot() instead of & it display the below error:
`ValueError: shapes (3,8) and (5,8) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)`

Comment: As I previously said, I cannot say what is wrong without seeing code. By the way, there is no need to use `.dot` here AFAIK (and this is clearly not a replacement for &).

Comment: i tried  your answer on 2 fields  **name** and **loc** 
 and now it display this error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'`

Comment: This means one of the mask is of type `str` and not `bool`. This is not possible with the code provided in the question: masks are always array of boolean. You should check the type in each case in your modified code. You can just print the type using `print(type(...))` or simply use a debugger.

Comment: all the field except **age** are object where age is int

Comment: i will add the result that show based on your answer